# Using rails send an email when column value chnge from nil to non-nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, models

I want to send an email to user when its value changing from nil to non nil value.
following conditions should get satisfied

1. Value is non-nil while creating An email should be sent to user, no mail should be sent to user after updating table.
2. Value is nil while creating.After update it should check that value is non-nil
   and if value is change from nil to no-nil an email should get send to the user

I want generalised method to do so as i have created object from several places and it's not possible for me to put code everywhere to send an email

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect job for an [observer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, i am using rails 2.3.8

Comment: No problem, observers where part of Rails since 1.2.3 (probably even before that).

Comment: will you please give me a piece of code so that it'll help me??

Comment: Sorry. I'd be happy to solve a problem, but I won't do the thinking and the work for you.